# Assembly CultureInfo and Application Pool in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have found a terribly puzzling behavior in ASP.Net/IIS.

Situation:

- A webproject, (.net 4.5.1), using MVC
- Deployed on AWS Windows 2008R2STD using webdeploy
- The IIS application uses an app pool identity
- The main assembly of my WebProject has

  ```
  [assembly: AssemblyCulture("fr-FR")]
  ```

Problem:

When I publish using the VS2013 wizard, the application works fine.

But if, for some reason, the apppool is recycled/restarded, like caused by a web.config edit, or an iisreset, the iis application does not start anymore, giving me 403 errors on the root and 404 on subrequests.

**Removing the "fr-FR" of the AssemblyCulture attribute fixes the problem.**

How did I end up trying that? Well, desperation I guess, and an article somewhere on SO that suggested looking at cultures related to 0x8xxxx errors (But I cannot find the article anymore)

So, I am puzzled. What is the link between Assembly Culture and IIS App Pool Identity (if any)?